# How to do this tablelayout in android?

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have to make a table layout like this. I have been trying in a lot of ways, but I cant do the same.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the edit texts the same size?

Comment: Post a link to your image, a user with more reputation can add it to the question for you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pclorq5lhy8qsjw/SC20121111-202233.png
Than you for the idea, I didnt think it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do it like this with some modifications as per your requirement..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nombre : "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter your field"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/first_row"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Localizame" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nombre : "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter your field"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_below="@id/second_row"
        android:id="@+id/third_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Latitud : "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter your field"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fourth_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/third_row"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Anadir Amigo" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Enter your field"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, finally I could do it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) can easily achieve this.